# Proving a property in De Morgan residuated lattices

Tags: lattice-theory, universal-algebra

A residuated lattice  is an algebra $(L, \wedge, \vee,\odot, \rightarrow, 0, 1)$
of type $(2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0)$ satisfying the following axioms:

(RL1) $(L, \wedge, \vee)$ is a bounded lattice (the partial order is denoted by $\leq $);

(RL2) $(L, \odot, 1)$ is a commutative monoid;

(RL3) For every $x, y, z \in L$, $x \odot z \leq y$ iff $z\leq x\rightarrow y$ (residuation).

If L is a residuated lattice, then for  $x, y \in L$ we define
$$x^{\ast}= x\rightarrow 0\text{ and }x\oplus y :=(x^{\ast}\odot y^{\ast})^{\ast}=x^{\ast}\to y^{\ast\ast}.$$  A residuated lattice $L$ is called a
De Morgan residuated lattice if    $(x\wedge y)^{\ast} = x^{\ast}\vee y^{\ast}$
for all $x, y \in L$.

Now let $x, y\in L$, for a De Morgan  residuated lattice such that $x\wedge y\leq e$ and $x^ {\ast}\wedge y^ {\ast}\leq e$, where $e$ is a complemented element of $L$, that is, $e\vee e^ {\ast} =1$ and $e\wedge e^{\ast} =0$. How can we show that we have $x\leq e$ or $x^{\ast}\leq e$ or $y\leq e$ or $y^{\ast}\leq e$?

Comment: You can't, as it fails already in the 4-element Boolean algebra.